# Navigate to other screen after notification

Tags: notifications, background, navigation, initialization, onesignal

I'm using react-native-onesignal for get notification in mobile app. But after app installation and minimization I clicked by notification. App was opened but navigation didn't work.
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8688

Comment: you need to handle the notification in functions such as

These are function which will be called when notification is recieved by onesignal in your app.

onReceived(notification) {
...      }
    
onOpened(openResult) {
        ...
      }

Comment: I handle the notification via onReceived(notification) { ... } onOpened(openResult) { ... } functions and get notification data. After modal window is opened, where I have two buttons. If I press the Create new post  button, must open new screen for create post, but navigation don't work (android only)